# How does SQL Server Wildcard Character Range, eg [A-D], work with Case-sensitive Collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone explain the rules for how a wildcard character range, eg [A-D], works with a case-sensitive collation?

I would have thought the following

```
WHERE CharColumn LIKE '[A-D]%';
```

would return only records which start with an upper case A, B, C or D, and exclude records that start with a lower case a, b, c or d.

However, in reality, it appears to return records that start with an upper case A but also records that start with B or b, C or c and D or d.  It's like only the first character of the range is case-sensitive and the remaining characters in the range are not case-sensitive.

On the other hand, the following

```
WHERE CharColumn LIKE '[ABCD]%';
```

**does** only return records which start with an upper case A, B, C or D.  Yet I would have thought [A-D] would be equivalent to [ABCD].

I get the same results in SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Example:
(insert statements written with SQL Server 2008 row constructors for compactness.  If each value is given its own insert statement the script will work in SQL Server 2005)

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST_LIKE_Patterns
    ( 
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        CharColumn VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    );

--------------
INSERT INTO #TEST_LIKE_Patterns (CharColumn)
VALUES ('aaa'), ('aAA'), ('AAA'), ('Aaa');
--------------    
INSERT INTO #TEST_LIKE_Patterns (CharColumn)
VALUES ('bbb'), ('bBB'), ('BBB'), ('Bbb');
--------------
INSERT INTO #TEST_LIKE_Patterns (CharColumn)
VALUES ('ccc'), ('cCC'), ('CCC'), ('Ccc');
--------------    
INSERT INTO #TEST_LIKE_Patterns (CharColumn)
VALUES ('ddd'), ('dDD'), ('DDD'), ('Ddd');
--------------    
INSERT INTO #TEST_LIKE_Patterns (CharColumn)
VALUES ('eee'), ('eEE'), ('EEE'), ('Eee');
--------------    
INSERT INTO #TEST_LIKE_Patterns (CharColumn)
VALUES ('fff'), ('fFF'), ('FFF'), ('Fff');
--------------

-- Raw Data:
SELECT *
FROM #TEST_LIKE_Patterns;

SELECT *
FROM #TEST_LIKE_Patterns
WHERE CharColumn LIKE '[A-D]%';

-- Results:
/*
ID   CharColumn
--------------
3    AAA
4    Aaa
5    bbb
6    bBB
7    BBB
8    Bbb
9    ccc
10   cCC
11   CCC
12   Ccc
13   ddd
14   dDD
15   DDD
16   Ddd
*/


SELECT *
FROM #TEST_LIKE_Patterns
WHERE CharColumn LIKE '[ABCD]%';    

-- Results:
/*
ID   CharColumn
    --------------
3    AAA
4    Aaa
7    BBB
8    Bbb
11   CCC
12   Ccc
15   DDD
16   Ddd
*/
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a binary collation as indicated in [Md. Elias Hossain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8411900/73226).

The explanation is that ranges in the pattern syntax work off Collation sort order rules.

[From BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> In range searches, the characters included in the range may vary
>   depending on the sorting rules of the collation.

So

```
;WITH T(C) AS
(
SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 'D' UNION ALL
select 'a' union all
select 'b' union all
select 'c' union all
select 'd'
)
SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY C COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Returns

```
C
----
a
A
b
B
c
C
d
D
```

So the range `A-D` excludes `a` but includes the other 3 lower case letters under a `CS` collation.

Comment: Thanks, this perfectly answers my question.  I was trying to understand the logic behind the apparently arbitrary results from a range search.  It's very clear now.  Cheers, Simon.

Answer (score 10):

It can be done in either way:

a. Use `COLLATE` while create the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST_LIKE_Patterns
( 
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CharColumn VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
);
```

b. Use `COLLATE` while selecting data as

```
SELECT *
FROM #TEST_LIKE_Patterns
WHERE CharColumn LIKE '%[A-D]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware you could specify the collation in a WHERE clause.  That will be most useful when querying databases I haven't designed.  Also, I hadn't thought to use a binary collation instead of a case-sensitive one.  Cheers, Simon

Comment: Using `Latin1_General_BIN` instead of `Latin1_General_CS_AS` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

try

```
SELECT *
FROM #TEST_LIKE_Patterns
WHERE CharColumn  LIKE '[A-D]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a case-sensitive collation works for search strings that are not in a range e.g. this would work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM #TEST_LIKE_Patterns
 WHERE (
        CharColumn LIKE 'A%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
        OR CharColumn LIKE 'B%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
        OR CharColumn LIKE 'C%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
        OR CharColumn LIKE 'D%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
       );
```

...but clearly that's not an acceptable approach!

As others have suggested, use `Latin1_General_BIN` for ranges.

Comment: `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` is used while creating the table and that is not working, your query provides same result(no change).

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain: thanks, I didn't test properly. Now updated.