# Identifying Latin Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following only returns surnames that are one character long.
Can I add a further condition so that it only returns Latin alphabet characters i.e. A-Z (plus a-z)

```
SELECT Surname
FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimUser
WHERE 
    LEN(Surname) =1
    AND <extra condition required>
GROUP BY Surname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Surname
FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimUser
WHERE 
    LEN(Surname) = 1
    AND Surname like '[a-Z]'
GROUP BY Surname
```

[Wildcard matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179884.aspx)

**Edit after comment below:**

Let's test:

```
create table t1 (c1 char(1) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
                 , c2 char(1) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
                 , wild1 varchar(10) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
                , wild2 varchar(10) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS)

insert into t1 values ('A', 'a', '[A-z]', '[a-Z]')

select match1 = case when c1 like wild1 then 'Matched' else 'Unmatched' end
  , match2 = case when c1 like wild2 then 'Matched' else 'Unmatched' end
  , match3 = case when c2 like wild1 then 'Matched' else 'Unmatched' end
  , match4 = case when c2 like wild2 then 'Matched' else 'Unmatched' end
from t1
```

[image]

You can see that both `A` and `a` are only matched correctly when `[a-Z]` is used as the match pattern.

[SQL Fiddle for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cd0c/1).

This can be explained in [the answer to this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410523/how-does-sql-server-wildcard-character-range-eg-a-d-work-with-case-sensitive). Basically, with `Latin1_General_CS_AS`, SQL server will sort characters like:

```
a
A
b
B
```

However, to steal from the question again, Books Online states:

```
In range searches, the characters included in the range may vary depending on the sorting rules of the collation.
```

So I guess it's COLLATION dependent to some extent, so really a case of testing in any particular environment where something liken this is deployed.

Comment: That works? I'd use 'a-zA-Z' ... just to spare out the characters in the ASCII table between 'Z' and 'a'. And since 'a' is after 'Z' in the ascii table, I'd assume you only match the surnames 'Z', '[', '/', ']', '^', '_', '`' and 'a' ...

Comment: Woah, that's an extensive analysis. Good work, Ian Preston! (I just hope it's useful for someone; if not, at least you worked on your geek cred ;)

Comment: Probably a long shot, but any chance of an explanation from whoever made the downvote today? I can update it if someone has a genuine issue.