# SQL Server LIKE operator with character range and case sensitive column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you explain me why following query returns rows which does not fulfill LIKE condition.
Column in the table has case sensitive collation, so query shouldn't return anything.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (col CHAR COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E');
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE col LIKE '[b-d]';
```

Any other case sensitive collation (ie. Latin1_General_100_CS_AS, Polish_100_CS_AS, Modern_Spanish_100_CS_AS) also doesn't work correctly.

As far as I can found only binary sort order collections (Latin1_General_100_BIN2, Modern_Spanish_100_BIN2) works well.

This error exist only when I use range in LIKE condition. When I change [b-d] to [bcd] everything is OK.

Is it a bug in database engine?

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5846.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: See for more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410523/how-does-sql-server-wildcard-character-range-eg-a-d-work-with-case-sensitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not a bug.

The range in the pattern syntax is not a regular expression. It defines a range under the collation sort order.

Those collations sort `AaBbCcDd...YyZz` (with upper case and lower case intermingled) so this is an expected result.

Binary collations sort `AB .... YZ .... ab ... yz`  (with upper case and lower case separated)  which is why it works correctly for those.

Comment: This explains everything. Thanks.

Comment: According to your case-insensitive example, [b-d] should match d but not D. Is that really the case? Appears not to: `SELECT 1 WHERE 'D' LIKE '[b-d]'`.

Comment: @usr - Maybe I got it the wrong way round and it sorts the upper case first. But principle is correct.

Comment: @usr - corrected. So would need to be `SELECT 1 WHERE 'B' LIKE '[b-d]' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`. Actually for `Latin1_General_CS_AS` it is the other way round with lower case first though.

Answer (score 2):

To show the order of the example you posted in your answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (col CHAR);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e');
-- This will work (ABCDEabcde):
SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY col COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
-- These will order letters:
SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY col COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY col COLLATE Polish_100_CS_AS
SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY col COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CS_AS
SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY col COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```