# like '%[a-z]%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS still return upper case?

Tags: sql-server

Running

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION');
```

returns `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

However, both the following SQL returns `ABC`. Shouldn't they return no row?

```
with t as (select 'ABC' X)
select *
from t 
where X like '%[a-z]%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;

with t as (select 'ABC' X)
select *
from t 
where X collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS like '%[a-z]%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a double headed issue of the collation with ranges using `LIKE`

This fails to return the value

```
create table t (x varchar(4))
insert into t values ('ABC')


select *
from t 
where X collate Latin1_General_CS_AS like '%a%' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

But this will

```
select *
from t 
where X collate Latin1_General_CS_AS like '%a%' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

In [range searches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as you have...

> The characters included in the range may vary depending on the sorting
>   rules of the collation

So, this collation and how it's handling the range which, I admit, isn't what I'd expect. If you list the values explicitly, as in all letters, [it works as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3a24abd94155d19bbb3d60b408b52cd7).

To fix this, as [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) stated in the comments, you [need to use Latin1_General_BIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412323/6167855)

Comment: This a great answer. The OP can "solve" their issue by using a binary collation with their original question. Latin1_General_BIN

Comment: Ah @SeanLange for the win!

Comment: @SeanLange, it feels so random that `Latin1_General_CS_AS` doesn't work but `Latin1_General_BIN` works.